# Redirect to another component with url passing id like parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

In TodoForm.jsx I'm creating a todo and when I'm clicking in create button, response who is in New Todo.jsx is undefined.

Consequently, todo id passed like parameter by url is undefined. I see '/todos/undefined/show' instead '/todos/134ls5/show' with data I filled up in Todo Form where 134ls5 is id from created todo.

More information, see [In BillForm create or edit a todo and redirect to ShowTodo not ListTodo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348827/in-billform-create-or-edit-a-todo-and-redirect-to-showtodo-not-listtodo)

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in this question*, don't make people traipse over to your last attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this would work.

Pretty sure the todoId you were trying to access was undefined in end URL because you were setting it within the then statement and it wasn't a part of the state. So when the rerender was triggered by the state update it was resetting it to null.

```
class NewTodo extends Component {
    state = {
        redirect: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.newTodo();
    }

    //In the following lines have to do much lines. I need to get todo if from api rest.

    submit = todo => {
        return this.props
            .saveTodo(todo)
            .then(response => {
                console.info(response);
                this.setState({ redirect: response._id});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                throw new SubmissionError(this.props.errors);
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>New Todo</h2>

                {this.state.redirect ? (
                    <Redirect to={"/todos/" + this.state.redirect + "/show"} />
                ) : (
                    <TodoForm todo={this.props.todo} onSubmit={this.submit} />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Since an empty string is falsy, the ternary condition should only ever evaluate to true one the redirect property of state has been set.